# .NET WinForms Editor Control that supports RTL\Hebrew and export to OOXML\PDF?

Tags: c#, .net, editor, pdf-generation, openxml

I'm interested in replacing an aging control we use in our project that is a simple HTML WYSIWYG editor.
The main requirements i'm looking for are as follows:

1. Support for RTL/Hebrew input.
2. Support for custom numbering styles
   (not just 1. 2. 3., A. B. C., etc).
3. Support fo exporting the content to
   OOXML (for Word 2007 inclusion) and
   PDF.

If anyone can recommand any control/component to review, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [TextControl](http://www.textcontrol.com/), it supports DOCX, DOC, PDF, HTML among other formats.

The control supports Unicode, so maybe it supoort Hebrew.